# Unable to "paint" text with the type tool with Illustrator CS6

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I am completely unable to "paint" text with the type tool.

What I mean by painting is I can't click and drag to select the text, therefore I can't select specific parts of the text to modify and I can't move the text around when using Type on a path, among other things.

Comment: maybe you locked it? Try Object menu > Unlock All

Comment: No, I have nothing locked. Same issue with all text assets I have. I can modify the text all I want, it's just I can't select it, which means that I can't move it when using Type on a path for example.

Comment: Sounds like it's not actual editable text, but has been converted to outlines.

Comment: Locked layer maybe? Show us a screenshot with the layers panel open.

Comment: BTW it's not called "paint" - you are trying to highlight the text.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your layers are locked. You can't do any edits to locked layers.

Hit <kbd>F7</kbd> and check the layers panel.

Answer (score 1):

> "I can modify the text all I want, it's just I can't select it"

The fact that you **can** modify the text, would indicate that perhaps the highlighting may simply be turned off.

`View > Show Edges` may show the highlighting you are expecting.